Is it secure when using the same choice scalar x in different VOLE instances?
Vector Oblivious Linear Evaluation(VOLE) allows a sender and a receiver obtain additive secret share about the product of a scalar and a vector. The receiver sends a random scalar $x$ to VOLE as input, and the sender sends two random vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ as input in VOLE. Then VOLE returns $\vec{y}=\vec{a}x+\vec{b}$ to the receiver.
I want to use the same choice scalar $x$ in $n$ VOLE instances as Receiver with $n$ parties $P_i(i\in [n])$. Each party $P_i$ sends $\vec{a}_i$ and $\vec{b}_i$ in each VOLE instance. Finally, I should obtain $\vec{y}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\vec{y}_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\vec{a}_{i}x+\vec{b}_i$ . Is it still secure about the scalar $x$?


To make the question understandable to general readers, you should recall what VOLE is, and say what $v$, $u_i$, $w_i$, and $\Delta$ are. I should be able to answer once you do that :)

Sorry about the confusion, I have modified the description of the problem.

Yes, this is perfectly fine. The VOLE security guarantees that the sender cannot infer anything about $x$ in each instance. In fact, this is commonly done in some works (the keyword is "programmable pseudorandom correlation generator") to generate $n$-party correlations from 2-party correlations, by fixing part of the correlation to remain the same across instances.

I'm reading your paper "Efficient pseudorandom correlation generators: silent OT extension and more", and  it helps  me a lot!  Thanks for your work! :)
